# I'm with an error ir R Unable to load librarys in R

Tags: r

I have reinstaled the windows, and now I'm using windows 11, and I'm facing this problems

After turn on the pc and open R this error appear:

During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) :
unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.1/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  The network path was not found.

And then I try to load tidyverse package and this error appear

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.1/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  The network path was not found.

The R version is 4.2.1

Comment: Have you tried removing/uninstalling your current R installation and then re-installing R? An OS upgrade may mean that you need to upgrade/reinstall R.

Comment: I did it... I removed all R versions e re-installed R, twice...

Comment: So just I understand a couple of yes/no questions: (1) You did a fresh/clean install of Windows 11? (2) You installed a clean version of R (which should be 4.2.1)? (3) You installed any non base-R dependencies (e.g. `install.packages('tidyverse')`)?

Comment: Do you have an `.RProfile` or `.Renviron` file in your home directory? That may be left over from an older version and could be messing things up.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I re-installed R(4.2.2 version) and I'm facing this same problem

During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.2/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The network path was not found.

Comment: When I try to load other packages the same happens

Failed with error:  ‘package ‘ggplot2’ could not be loaded’
Carregando pacotes exigidos: ade4
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ade4’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.2/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The network path was not found.